# Review Audit Blocking Algorithm

Tags: discussion

I am curious as to how the audit review blocking works.  At what point does failure in audit questions cause an account to be blocked from further reviews?  What are the blocking periods?  After blocking periods are over at what point do additional blocks occur?

Answer (score 7):

meta.SE is the place for this sort of question...

[Getting suspended from reviewing isn't clearly defined:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214156/130540)

> When you fail an audit, the review system looks at your past review history, and takes into account not just how many audits you've failed, but also a few other heuristics intended to help identify folks who've gotten careless or just aren't paying attention at all. If the results are sufficiently damning, you get a short break. If you come back and do the same thing, you get a longer break.

[Length of review suspensions is given here:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190562/130540)

```
 each review ban counts (even manual ones made by moderators).  
 a 30 day window is used  
 1st ban within the window -> duration: 2 days  
 2nd ban within the window -> duration: 7 days   
 3rd ban within the window -> duration: 30 days
```

Given the way other stuff works in SE, I'd guess that if you keep getting suspended, the system will look more closely at your voting patterns...

Comment: We recently asked the SE team to review the audit-ban process as some users were failing ***a lot*** of audits but were *not* getting banned. I didn't see any official decree that something has changed (so perhaps it hasn't changed), but I see some users are getting banned now, looks like it started mid August 2014.

Comment: I think that the changes to the audit-ban algorithm are way too sensitive now.

Comment: @mdpc You failed more than a few audits... It seems pretty accurate if not forgiving.

Comment: @chris - Re-banning after only a very few audit-ban  "errors" (5 within a month) is pretty aggressive.  Especially since I have some disagreement with some of the "answer" criteria used.

Comment: @mdpc Sure, but it took a few more than 5 to get the first ban. I think they expect you to be more careful after you've been banned once, and then twice...

Comment: My impression is that the audits have been a bit better lately (last several months).  Although bad audits show up once in a while (where the question really deserves the vote you gave, but the review algorithm says your vote is wrong), I haven't noticed as many recently.  If you're paying attention and truly reviewing the questions, it's rare to make a mistake.

Comment: Too bad there isn't a button to "dispute" the results and provide the rationale.  This would help to tune the system better.